# Howto - JavaScript Replace which finds all instances not just the first

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, preg-replace

I have the following function:

```
listorder = listorder.replace('projectlist-','');
```

Problem with this is it only finds and replace the first instance and there are many. How can this be updated to Find/Replace All instances in the string?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Global replace (all instances)

```
listorder = listorder.replace(/projectlist-/g,'');
```

Case-insensitive replace

```
listorder = listorder.replace(/projectlist-/i,'');
```

Global and case-insensitive

```
listorder = listorder.replace(/projectlist-/gi,'');
```

Comment: What if the first argument to replace() is a variable rather than a string? I can't seem to get it working...

Comment: @JamieCarruthers in that case you'll need to use a RegExp object (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) and use it as the first parameter of `replace()`.